# How to find the longest occurrence of a string in a column and corresponding first and last values from another column in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

## Data

```
df <- data.frame(Vehid = rep(c(1,2,3), each=15), gap = c(rep(5,3), rep(7,2), 20,20,21,21,22,23,24,28,29,30, 20,20,21,21,22,23,24,28,29,30, rep(7,5), rep(5,3), rep(7,3), rep(5,3), 7, 20,24,26,28,30),
                                                          State = c(rep('Following',3), rep('.',2), rep('Following',10), rep('Following',10), rep('.',5), rep('Following',3), rep('.',3), rep('Following',3), '.', rep('Following',5)))
```

## Required

The `Vehid` is unique ID of a vehicle, `gap` is the distance it keeps behind another vehicle, and `State` tells whether a vehicle is 'Following' (technical term in Traffic Engineering) another vehicle or not.
You can see that in this sample `df`, one vehicle could have more than one instances where 'Following' occurrs consecutively. The `.` indicates 'Not Following'. I want to find the LONGEST occurrence of the 'Following' state for every `Vehid` and find the first and last value of `gap` for that occurrence.

## Desired Output

```
df2 <- data.frame(Vehid = rep(c(1,2,3), each=15), gap = c(rep(5,3), rep(7,2), 20,20,21,21,22,23,24,28,29,30, 20,20,21,21,22,23,24,28,29,30, rep(7,5), rep(5,3), rep(7,3), rep(5,3), 7, 20,24,26,28,30),
                 State = c(rep('Following',3), rep('.',2), rep('Following',10), rep('Following',10), rep('.',5), rep('Following',3), rep('.',3), rep('Following',3), '.', rep('Following',5)),
                 dx_safe = rep(20,45), dx_CC2 = rep(30,45))
```

`dx_safe` is the `gap` at the first `Following` string of the longest occurrence and `dx_CC2` is the last.

## What I tried

I can't figure out anything! Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the longest run, i'll pretty much use the `rle` function. I'll also take care of splitting the data by Vehicle ID with `split` and later recombining with `do.call(rbind())`. I wind up with

```
dx<-do.call(rbind, (lapply(split(df,df$Vehid), function(x){
    rr <- rle(x$State=="Following")
    i <- which.max(rr$lengths * rr$values)
    v <- x$gap[c((s<-sum(c(0,rr$lengths)[1:i]))+1, s+rr$lengths[i])]
    data.frame(Vehid=x$Vehid[1], dx_safe=v[1], dx_CC2=v[2])
})))
```

which returns

```
  Vehid dx_safe dx_CC2
1     1      20     30
2     2      20     30
3     3      20     30
```

then, to re-join with the original data, you can do a simple merge.

```
merge(df, dx)
```

which should look like your desired output.

Comment: thanks for your answer. When I used this code for my original data frame it gave me this error: `Error in 1:i : argument of length 0`. What could be causing this?

Comment: Perhaps there are groups without any "Following" values? Hard to say. It works on the test data. If your real data has different properties then it would help if your test data more closely resembled the real data, or at least contains the records that would cause such an error.

Comment: My original data set is quite big (more than million rows). I looked at some of the `Vehid`s and created the sample data. Maybe you are right about the missing 'Following' values. How can I modify this code if there are some `Vehid`s with missing 'Following'?

Comment: It depends on what you expect to happen in that case. You didn't define a behavior for that scenario. Have you tried running the code on just a subset of the rows? Perhaps you can find a small subset that recreates the error just to make sure that's the reason.